# Record audio from Pepper robot with GStreamer

Tags: audio, gstreamer, audio-recording, pepper

I'm working with the Pepper robot from SoftBank Robotics and GStreamer for RTP stream. I need to record the audio from the robot. I use gstreamer1.0 on my computer and gstreamer0.10 is installed on the robot.
Here are the command lines I use :

Pepper:

```
gst-launch-0.10 alsasrc name=mic provide-clock=true do-timestamp=true buffer-time=200000 mic. ! 'audio/x-raw-int, format=S16LE; channels=1, width=16, depth=16, rate=16000' ! udpsink host="computer_adress" port="speaker_port" sync=false
```

Computer:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e udpsrc port="speaker_port" ! audio/x-raw, width=16, depth=16, rate=16000, channels=1 format=S16LE ! audioconvert ! filesink location=audio_file_name.mp3 sync=false
```

With these commands I only can get a mp3 file but with no sound in it.
I'm aware that some things are not correct but I don't know what. I'm a beginner with Gstreamer and RTP protocol. Could someone help me with that ? And maybe explain me how to stream audio with RTP from the robot.

Sorry if I made any English writing mistakes.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Which OS installed on the pepper robot? Android or Python?

Comment: @androider The OS is NAOqi OS, using Python

Comment: Can you test recording an audio file with `arecord` to see if that works? `arecord -d 5 -f S16_LE -c 1 -r 16000 -t wav out.wav` will record 5 seconds of audio to the file `out.wav`. If this works it confirms that Pepper's microphones are working correctly.

Comment: @DominicD yes it works

Comment: Did you notice that you are not using RTP in your GStreamer pipeline? Also, the capabilities you use at both ends of the network are not exactly the same: one is `audio/x-raw-int` and the other is `audio/x-raw`.

Comment: @VictorPaléologue It's true, thank you